# Confirm windows calls many times

Tags: javascript, arrays

I made a to-do list and wanted a confirm window to pop up every time I clicked on a task, asking if the user wanted to delete it. And everything seems to work, but if the task is the first in the list, then the window with the question is called once, if the task is the second in the list, then the window is already called twice, etc.

Can you help me fix this problem or point me in the right direction, please

```
addButton = document.getElementById('addButton');
taskInput = document.getElementById('taskInput');
taskList = document.getElementById('taskList');

    function addTheTask() {
        listItem = document.createElement('li');
        listItem.textContent = taskInput.value;
        taskList.appendChild(listItem);
        const taskListElements = document.querySelectorAll('ul li');
        const arrItems = Array.from(taskListElements);
        arrItems.forEach(element => {
                element.addEventListener('click', () => {
                       let question = window.confirm(`Do you realy want to delete this task? '${element.textContent}'`)
                if (question == true) {
                    element.remove();
                }
                })    
            }
        );
        taskInput.value = '';
    }


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style src="./style.css"></style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>To-do list</h1>
    <input id="taskInput" type="text" placeholder="Add your task!">
    <button id="addButton" onclick="addTheTask()">Add</button>
    <ul id="taskList">

    </ul>
    <script src="./script.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: We can only help you if you provide us with the code for a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more info.

Comment: Sorry, I've already sent the code

Comment: because you keep binding events to elements that have events. You should not be looping over all the elements, but only the new one.

Comment: Also why are you confirming after you already remove the element?

Comment: Oh, thanks, I just saw it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you add a new task you are selecting every li and you are adding an event listener to them.

Just bind the element you create. Do not select them all.

```js
function addTheTask() {
  // create the new list item
  const element = document.createElement('li');
  element.textContent = taskInput.value;

  // bind the element listener to remove it
  element.addEventListener('click', () => {

    // ask to confirm they actually meant to remove it
    const question = window.confirm(`Do you really want to delete this task? '${element.textContent}'`)
    
    // if they approved the removal, remove it
    if (question) element.remove();
  });

  // add the new item to the list
  taskList.appendChild(element);


  // clear the input value
  taskInput.value = '';
}
```

Other option is you do not add multiple events, but you use event delegation.

```js
function addTheTask() {
  // create the new list item
  const listItem = document.createElement('li');
  listItem.textContent = taskInput.value;

  // add the new item to the list
  taskList.appendChild(listItem);


  // clear the input value
  taskInput.value = '';
}



// bind the element listener to the UL and listen
taskList.addEventListener('click', (evt) => {

  // determine what li element was clicked on
  const element = evt.target.closest("li");

  // if no li was found, ignore the click
  if (!element) return;

  // ask to confirm they actually meant to remove it
  const question = window.confirm(`Do you realy want to delete this task? '${element.textContent}'`)

  // if they approved the removal, remove it
  if (question) element.remove();
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you have solved my problem.
But I don't understand how exactly JS understands which item in the list I'm clicking on.
Because of this, I did everything with an array

Comment: Whoops, sorry I left the old variable names there when I was editing it. I fixed it.

Comment: That is, when I create a new task, an event is added to this very task, and when I click on this task, JS understands which task I am referring to?
Sorry for the dumb questions

Comment: Because you store it in the variable.... `const element = document.createElement('li');` is the reference to the element. The event listener references that variable to remove it.

Comment: I'm a little stupid
I thought that when I click the button, a function is called that creates a li, and when I click the button again, this function overwrites the already created li. And I could not understand how js understands which li to delete, because we only have 
const listItem = document.createElement('li'); 
creates a variable with the same name